# how to call a javascript function from my custom CDVPlugin class (Objective C Language)

Tags: ios, objective-c, cordova, plugins

I have created a custom (`CDVPlugin`) Plugin in `Cordova` app.

Through that plugin if javascript file calls a method which is declared in `CDVPlugin` then i can easily send response through

```
CDVPluginResult *pluginResult = nil;
pluginResult = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_OK messageAsString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",deviceUUIDString]];
self.delegateCallbackId=command.callbackId;
[self.commandDelegate sendPluginResult:pluginResult callbackId:command.callbackId];
```

But how to call a javascript function from my custom CDVPlugin class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer if we want to call any javascript method call it with evalJs which is declared in `CDVCommandDelegate`Class and can write the name of the function as string with semicolon

In Cordova : 
we can use  evaluateJavaScript method like this

`[self.commandDelegate evalJs:@"callCustomMethodJs();"];`

Answer (score 0):

You can try following

```
NSString * jsfunctioncall = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"yourjsfunctiontobecalled()"];

#ifdef __CORDOVA_4_0_0
    [self.webViewEngine evaluateJavaScript:jsfunctioncall completionHandler:nil];
#else
    [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsfunctioncall];
#endif
```

CDVPlugin has webViewEngine and webView as its properties,so if you have inherited from CDVPlugin it will probably work.For this to work your JS probably needs to be already loaded.I haven't tried it myself.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks for your help , but i tried this way    `NSString * jsfunctioncall = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"callCustomMethodJs()"];

    viewController=[[CDVViewController alloc
                     ] init];
    [viewController.webViewEngine evaluateJavaScript:jsfunctioncall completionHandler:nil];`
    with no success

Comment: Don't create object of CDVViewController.CDVPlugin has property webViewEngine and webView.You can call using that properties.JS needs to be loaded first to use "evaluateJavaScript".Post your updated code in question i.e where have you written this code.It might be helpful.